# input value showing one value but in display coming another value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, input

I am facing one rare issue can some one help me here.

```
<input class="testVal" type="number" id="GT_FIRING_TEMPERATURE" value="-17" name="degC" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().unitConversion(value,name, id)">
```

here value is "-17" but in display in input[type='number'] box it is showing my old value "1"
in div it is showing proper value -17
it works perfect in div instead of input filed :) I can't understand the problem 
[Please find image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcEoM.png)

Comment: Provide us some code man, we cant just guess whats happenning...

Comment: Can you post the HTML and controller?

Comment: <input class="testVal" type="number" id="GT_FIRING_TEMPERATURE" value="-17" name="degC" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().unitConversion(value‌​,name, id)"> I am using ng repeat to bind values to input box as per the id I am binding values, but here value is bind to input as valu="-17", but in display it showing my old value "1", please look into image

Comment: it works perfect in div instead of input filed :) I can't understand the problem what it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution I found my self

```
<input class="testVal" type="text"  id="{{item.param_type_value}}" ng-model="item.testCondition" value="{{item.testCondition}}" name="{{item.defUnit}}"    onchange="angular.element(this).scope().unitConversion(this.value,name, id)">
```

I missed ng-model, and value should be the same ng-model and input type should be text.

Answer (score 2):

Hello something must be wrong with your code,

it is very simple though to bind your input text to a variable.

### HTML

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <input type="number" ng-model="mynumber">
    {{mynumber}}
  </body>
```

### JS

```
$scope.mynumber = 0;
```

live example: https://plnkr.co/edit/Inr3vKhuWaulXhythSDk?p=preview

Comment: thanks for your quick reply Theo Itzaris  <input class="testVal" type="number" id="GT_FIRING_TEMPERATURE" value="-17" name="degC" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().unitConversion(value,name, id)"> 
 
I am using ng repeat to bind values to input box as per the id I am binding values, but here value is bind to input as valu="-17", but in display it showing my old value "1", please look into image

Comment: You dont have to do it so complicated. just add 'ng-change' like :  <input type="number" ng-model="mynumber" ng-change="valueChange()">  and into controller add the 'valueChange' function. I updated the plunker example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as you have not provided full details:
in your unitConversion function pass this.value

```
<input class="testVal" type="number" id="GT_FIRING_TEMPERATURE" value="-17" name="degC" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().unitConversion(this.value,this.name, id)">
```

Comment: <input class="testVal" type="number" id="GT_FIRING_TEMPERATURE" value="-17" name="degC" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().unitConversion(value‌​,name, id)"> I am using ng repeat to bind values to input box as per the id I am binding values, but here value is bind to input as valu="-17", but in display it showing my old value "1", please look into the attached image

Comment: also please provide your js file

Comment: I am sure here problem with view only bcz it getting updated value for div, but not for input field. in input also value is updated but it is showing old value to view